# Change return type of child class

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a base class (BaseClass) that operates using objects of a base type (BaseType). I want a child class (ChildClass) that inherits from BaseClass but operates using objects of a child type (ChildType).

Is there a way to accomplish this without type hinting errors?

Consider the following code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class BaseType:
    name: str

@dataclass
class ChildType(BaseType):
    favoriteColor: str

class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, myThing: BaseType):
        self.myThing = myThing
    def get_my_thing(self) -> BaseType:
        return self.myThing

class ChildClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, myThing: ChildType):
        self.myThing = myThing
        self.do_something_super_complicated()
    def do_something_super_complicated():
        color = self.myThing.favoriteColor
        # do complicated things with color
```

ChildClass.get_my_thing() now has a return type of ChildType. How can I mark that this is the case? For instance, I don't want to get a type hint error by doing this:

```
cc = ChildClass(ChildType(name="bob", favoriteColor="red"))
print(cc.get_my_thing().favoriteColor)
# This causes a type hint error because return type of get_my_thing is BaseType which does not have favoriteColor
```

If I do the following, I still get a type hint error:

```
class ChildClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, myThing: ChildType):
        self.myThing = myThing
    def get_my_thing(self) -> ChildType:
        return super().get_my_thing() 
#The return type of super().get_my_thing() is BaseType so this causes a type hint error
```

Comment: A "type hint error" isn't an actual thing in Python, it's just a warning from your specific IDE or linter. But even if it was, since all `ChildType` instances are also `BaseType` instances, it's not wrong to annotate a method returing a `ChildType` with `-> BaseType`. You don't need to reimplement the `ChildClass`'s `__init__` or `get_my_thing` methods if they are the exact same methods of `BaseClass`.

Comment: Type hinting is still a feature of Python that I want to use, if possible

Comment: Yes it's a feature but there are no intrinsic "errors" to speak of. Unless you're using a third-party library that actually type-checks Python code during runtime, any "errors" you encounter are due to your particular choice of type-checker (e.g. PyCharm's warnings). It is not uncommon for such tools to raise false-positive warnings, stating that a type hint is "wrong" when it actually isn't.

Comment: 'error' might not be the right word but type-hinting is still an officially supported Python feature that I want to use

Answer (score 3):

There is value in that type hint error - a value of `BaseType` isn't necessarily a value of `ChildType`. Concretely, if `BaseType` is Car and `ChildType` is Tesla, `super().get_my_thing()` in `ChildClass` returns some Car, but you are trying to treat it specifically like a Tesla.

From your example, it seems that you want to model some class that takes in a generic type (that must be a subclass of `BaseType`) and has a method `get_my_thing` that has the generic type as its return type. You can consider to define a single class instead, as follow:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

@dataclass
class BaseType:
    name: str

@dataclass
class ChildType(BaseType):
    favoriteColor: str

T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseType)

class MyClass(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, myThing: T):
        self.myThing = myThing
    def get_my_thing(self) -> T:
        return self.myThing

class BaseClass(MyClass[BaseType]):
    pass

class ChildClass(MyClass[ChildType]):
    pass


base_type = BaseType("Bob")
base_instance = BaseClass(base_type)
base_instance.get_my_thing().name               # OK

child_type = ChildType("Bob", "blue")
child_instance = ChildClass(child_type)
child_instance.get_my_thing().name              # OK
child_instance.get_my_thing().favoriteColor     # OK
```

The type hinting works on my editor (VS Code, using the Pylance language server for checking type hints).

Comment: This code raises an actual error on the `T = TypeVar('T', BaseType)` line: `TypeError: A single constraint is not allowed` (using Python 3.9).

Comment: I like where this is going, but is there a way to keep the two separate classes? My example was too simple to demonstrate but let's say there's stuff I want to do in ChildClass that relates to the stuff in ChildType

Comment: See updated snippet - defining BaseClass and ChildClass to derive from the base class that defines the base methods with respect to the generic type param. As mentioned by others, type hinting in Python is more of an IDE helper, so augmenting your code in this way to support type hinting can come at the cost of more verbosity.

Comment: @AnsonMiu thanks for the updated version, upvoted. However, I still feel like this is more trouble than it is worth just to get an IDE to shut up. I agree that there is value in knowing whether a given method returns a `Car` or a `Tesla`, but if the BaseClass is called `CarFactory` and the ChildClass is called `TeslaFactory`, then I would say it is quite obvious which type of object is returned from the `get_vehicle` method. We should aim to make the code speak for itself in whichever context it is placed. Coding around a particular choice of tools is a bad idea IMO.

Comment: @jfaccioni I agree; for the sake of the question, it's cool to see that Python's typing module is expressive enough to model the needs of the question. But for day-to-day work, I'd go as far as type annotations. If I need to change the structure of the code to get some IDE tooling, maybe I'll reconsider using Python in the first place :)